# How to use json sub-element in where clause, on MYSQL JSON field type?

Tags: mysql, json, regex, where-clause, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7 implemented JSON data type.

Imagine a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
```

With values:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"val": 1, "color": null, "status": "error" }');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"val": 2, "color": "blue", "status": "success" }');
```

I would like to know how to use json sub-values in where operations such as:

```
 - =
 - BETWEEN
 - >
 - >=
 - <=
 - Like(JSON_CONTAINS?)
 - !=, <>
 - REGEXP
 - IS NULL
 - IS NOT NULL
 - IS NOT
```

How can I use this json data in a basic where operations? Is it possible? Is it Partially possible? For what types of operation?

Comment: read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html
contains all the answer to your question

Comment: Also see: [12.16.3 Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).